# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the constructor in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, repository

I use the following code for dependency injection of Register/Login controller. The problem is that I cannot use Repository pattern I have created previously.

```
private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public HomeController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }
```

When I run the code, the following error is occured:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'CustomizedIdentity.Repositories.IUserRepository' while attempting to
> activate 'CustomizedIdentity.Controllers.HomeController'.

I need to use repository for getting information from user table.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. I need to use the following code to create the service:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```